# Customizing Equation-Numbering / Labeling in IEEEeqnarray

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering, ieeetran

I'm trying to label a set of functions as a specific number (9.125), like how equations are usually labeled with `\begin{equation}` or `\begin{IEEEeqnarray}`. I have been using `\tag{}` (with a customized number like 9.034 inside the `\tag`, so each equation is individually labeled with my own choice of text/writing) for most of my document and I don't want to have to change all those again just so I can get this one section right (40 page document!).

This is what I want to be labeled (9.125):

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{LR}
\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=0,\qquad&\qquad\frac{e}{f}-\frac{g}{h}=0 \\[10pt]
\frac{i}{j}+\frac{k}{l}=0,\qquad&\qquad\frac{m}{n}+\frac{o}{p}=0
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

I know commands like `\IEEEyesnumber` and I'm aware of people changing the labels of subsections and what not inside `IEEEeqnarray`. I just want to give this equation (no sub-equations or etc) a customizable label, where it functions the same way as `\tag`. I don't even want to "reference" it like a label throughout the text, that's not even necessary, I just want the number 9.125 in brackets to appear to the side exactly like it would in `\begin{equation}\tag{9.125}`. How can I accomplish this?

If it is of any use, which I don't think it should be, my preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=16.00cm, height=22.00cm]{geometry}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Ah, I knew how to do the four space indenting but not the backticks; thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I've set the entire `IEEEeqnarray` structure inside a `minipage`, inside an `equation`, which then allows you to use `\tag{9.125}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage[width=16.00cm, height=22.00cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{LR}
  \frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=0,\qquad&\qquad\frac{e}{f}-\frac{g}{h}=0 \\[10pt]
  \frac{i}{j}+\frac{k}{l}=0,\qquad&\qquad\frac{m}{n}+\frac{o}{p}=0
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\begin{equation}
  \makebox[0pt]{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{LR}
      \frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=0,\qquad&\qquad\frac{e}{f}-\frac{g}{h}=0 \\[10pt]
      \frac{i}{j}+\frac{k}{l}=0,\qquad&\qquad\frac{m}{n}+\frac{o}{p}=0
    \end{IEEEeqnarray*}
  \end{minipage}}
  \tag{9.125}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The `minipage` is actually also set in a zero-width box so that the equation number can overlap with the `IEEEeqnarray` block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will admit it seems like a bit of extra work, but if that's what necessary then so be it :P Thank you really, you have no idea how long I've tried fixing this and looking for answers!