# IEEEeqnarray: \tag-like command?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath, ieeetran

Is there a IEEEtrantools command equivalent to amsmath's `\tag`? Example:

```
Consider the well-known functor laws:
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  F(f \circ g) &=& F(f) \circ F(g) \tag{Fu1} \\
  F(id) &=& id \tag{Fu2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

(above code is ill-formed, I get "\tag not allowed here")

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147812/customizing-equation-numbering-labeling-in-ieeeeqnarray), but the (only) answer goes by putting the labelling outside the IEEEeqnarray.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please always post complete documents, not just fragments.

You can locally define `\theequation` to be your label, but you need to get into the right place first.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ztag[1]{%
\def\@currentlabel{#1}%
\gdef\tmp{%
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
\def\theequation{#1}}%
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup
\tmp}
\begin{document}
\makeatother

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  F(f \circ g) &=& F(f) \circ F(g) \ztag{Fu1}\label{a} \\
  F(id) &=& id \ztag{Fu2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  F(f \circ g) &=& F(f) \circ F(g\label{b})  \\
  F(id) &=& id 
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

[\ref{a}] [\ref{b}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you computed the number of \aftergroup's? Always happy to learn new things.

Comment: @rainmaker well it's always 2^n-1, I thought it was going to be 3 (without looking at the ieee sources) but it ended up needing 31:-)

Comment: Eh, almost! Just noticed that if I do `\ztag{Fu1} \label{ax:Fu1}` (or the other way round), a `\ref{ax:Fu1}` (or `\eqref`) will always print the (incorrect) number of the equation, in your case (1), not (Fu1).
I guess that's because the counter is not yet changed when \label is evaluated. Any idea?

Comment: @rainmaker oh I meant to mention that, updated with a line to set the `\label`

Comment: Have been using this for a while now with great success. Just to mention a bug I just hit, for the archives:
The `\ztag` command *has* to be placed in the last column. E.g. if you just have content in the leftmost column, you still have to do `my stuff goes here && \ztag{Foo}`.
Otherwise, the tag is not set, and I think even equation numbers are messed up.

Comment: @rainmaker I'm sure that's a _design feature_ not a bug:-)