# \makebox causes "Underfull \hbox" warning when it's in an \NewDocumentEnvironment

Tags: koma-script, ieeetran

MWE:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass[fleqn, oneside, titlepage = false, fontsize = 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{cmun}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*rm,
    ItalicFont=*ti,
    BoldFont=*bx,
    BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{sustav3x3xyz}{b}
{%
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\begin{minipage}{6cm}
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rlCrlCrlCl}
        #1
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{minipage}}
}{}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149370/ieeeeqnarray-tag-like-command
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ztag[1]{%
\def\@currentlabel{#1}%
\gdef\tmp{%
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
\def\theequation{#1}}%
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup
\tmp}

\begin{document}

        \noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
        \begin{minipage}{6cm}
        \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rlCrlCrlCl}
            2&x &+& 2&y &-& 2&z & = & 1 \ztag{1}
            \\*
            3&x &+& 5&y &-& 2&z & = & 2 \ztag{2}
            \\*
            3&x &+& 5&y &-& &z & = & 3 \ztag{3}
            \addtocounter{equation}{1}
        \end{IEEEeqnarray}\end{minipage}}

        \begin{sustav3x3xyz}
            2&x &+& 2&y &-& 2&z & = & 1 \ztag{1}
            \\*
            3&x &+& 5&y &-& 2&z & = & 2 \ztag{2}
            \\*
            3&x &+& 5&y &-& &z & = & 3 \ztag{3}
        \end{sustav3x3xyz}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Systems of equations]

---

**Warning**

> `warning| Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph ...`

The warning refers to the second system of equations. If I remove that system, the warning goes away. Also, if I just remove the `\makebox` from the second system, the warning goes away. I use `\makebox` to center both systems horizontally. The code for both systems is nearly identical, except that the second system relies on `\NewDocumentEnvironment`.

Comment: underfull \hbox questions are normally easy, but you make a full time job out of it. Try to minimize your problem.

Comment: The problem is that I am new still a newbie so I am never sure what is and what isn't relevant to my problem. I edited my question.

Comment: A newbie using a sequence of 31 \aftergroup commands ??!?! HA!

Comment: @DonaldArseneau I just copied the command from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149370/ieeeeqnarray-tag-like-command, I have no idea what \aftergroup commands are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set \parfillskip to 0 in the environment, or (probably better) use \centering instead of this \makebox

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{sustav3x3xyz}{b}
{%\parfillskip=0pt % with the makebox
\centering
%\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
 \begin{minipage}{6cm}
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rlCrlCrlCl}
        #1
    \addtocounter{equation}{1}
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{minipage}%
%}
\par% for the centering
}{}
```

Btw: The ztag definition leads to duplicate destinations and so links will not work correctly:

```
warning  (pdf backend): ignoring duplicate destination with the name 'equation.1
.1.0'
```

Comment: When I use ztag, eqref gives the correct label but the hyperlink always leads to the first equation but at least it always leads to the correct block of equations so that's good enough.